# re.search is not working when the string is read from a tuple

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

output:

```
[----------] My test environment
[==========] 14 tests from 6 test cases ran
[  PASSED  ] 14 tests.\

(f, code, output) = entry
if output.find("My test environment) != -1:
for line in output.split("\n"):
    m = re.search("PASSED. *\] (\d+) tests", line)
    if m:
       total = total + int(m.group(1))
```

In this case line is read from output(string) which is being read from a tuple and m appears to be always none in this case. Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with the regular expression? This regular expression works fine when line is hard coded to a string or when line is read from file.

Answer (score 0):

your indentation after for loop seems to be wrong? and you mean m not M . i don't see any M ?

```
for line in output.split("\n"):
    m = re.search("PASSED. *\] (\d+) tests", line)
    if m:
      total = total + int(m.group(1))
```

Comment: thanks! sorry i have a proper indentation in code somehow i didn't format it properly here. yes i mean m. sorry for the typo. I have checked for the value in line in each iteration and it has the right values.

Comment: In the for loop i have hard coded the value of  line = "[   PASSED  ] 14 tests." and m.group(1) returns 14 (for  approx 1000 times) untill the loop terminates. I don't understand why it doesn't work when line is directly passed(without hardcoding its value) to it. I have printed the 'line' value in for loop and it prints each line from the output one after the other.

Comment: Do you a whole code? it is hard to understand what is causing the issue. Can you print "line" after for loop to see what is actually getting printed? also could you print "output" as well please. is it a string?

Comment: original code:
(f, code, output) = entry
if output.find("My test environment) != -1:
   for line in output.split("\n"):
        m = re.search("PASSED. *\] (\d+) tests", line)
        if m:
           total = total + int(m.group(1))
I have checked for the data type of line and output using type(line) and type(output) both has returned <type 'str'>
and type(entry) returned <type 'tuple'>

Comment: Sorry for the poor format. I didn't find a way to format the code. I am new to stackoverflow.
In for loop i have printed the value of line its exactly same as the one in output
line values are displayed as each time.
[----------] My test environment
[==========] 14 tests from 6 test cases ran
[  PASSED  ] 14 tests.

Comment: I tried same example it works perfectly fine, unless there is something else  you are missing. can i ask how entry is getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to iterate through the lines, you can use `re.MULTILINE`:

```
m = re.search("PASSED\s+\] (\d+) tests", output, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: I tested this with the one you posted and it works. You should update your question with the exact format of the string

Comment: The output you're showing is apparently not the same with what we have here

Comment: Output has 1000 lines of text , i have copied a small portion of it. When i print the value of output all 1000 lines are displayed and in each loop i have printed the value in line it has the printed the same lines in output. I have checked for the type of line, output and entry and they happened to be str,str and tuple.